# Rails.cache.write returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, memcached

I am running a rails app on Heroku using Memcached Cloud add-on. The app was set up by a developer that is now long gone.

I am trying to use memcache to store some temporary data, but I can not get it to work. Most confusing, is my calls to Rails.cache.write which return nil everytime.

I don't want to just jump in and muddle with the cache setup because it does appear to be working and this app is large enough and complex enough that I don't want to risk breaking anything.

I have googled for a while, but this nil return doesn't seem to be documented behaviour (it is nil, not false).

Console output:

```
$>heroku run rails console -app <myapp>
...
irb(main):002:0> Rails.cache.write("foo","bar")
Dalli::Server#connect pub-memcache-16992.xxxxxxxxx.com:16992
Dalli/SASL authenticating as memcached-appxxxxxxx
Dalli/SASL: Authenticated
=> nil
```

enviromments/production.rb

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store,
                   ENV["MEMCACHEDCLOUD_SERVERS"].split(','),
                   { :username => ENV["MEMCACHEDCLOUD_USERNAME"],   :password => ENV["MEMCACHEDCLOUD_PASSWORD"] }
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'dalli'
```

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Sorry, should say - Running rails 4.0.5 on ruby 2.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Facepalm*

The cache was full, so it could not write and nil is the documented response for the underlying dalli client.